# Can we apply border radius to the scroll bar in firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, firefox

I have a scroll bar in the chrome and I want make this scroll bar completable with firefox but not able to fins the way to give the radius for scroll-bar.

**Chrome scroll bar css**

```
/* Store selector */

/* width */
.lhh::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 6px;
  height: 56px !important;
}

/* Handle */
.lhh::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Looking for a solution how to give the border radius to the scroll bar for the mozila firefox.
some links [firefox css](https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/50474627.html#:%7E:text=Firefox%20scrollbar%20border%2Dradius&text=The%20radius%20applies%20to%20the,by%20the%20background%2Dclip%20property.)

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in Firefox browser, the only options you have is the color and the width you can achievie it by setting up those rules:

```css
scrollbar-color: red; /* your colors here */
scrollbar-width: thin;
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use -moz instead of -webkit

Comment: It doesn't work